# How to make more dynamic Postgres configuration?

Tags: postgresql

I am running PostgreSQL 11 on EC2 instances that can be scaled up and down. Everytime an instance is scaled his memory specs can change. If in my configuration I have for example something like this:

```
effective_cache_size = 400GB
```

in case of big instances, if I scale the machine down of course that configuration memory won't work any more blocking the db instance from starting. So a better solution would be something like:

```
effective_cache_size = 80%
```

but that won't work. So apart writing lots of different file configurations, is there a way to have a sort of "dynamic" Postgres configuration?

Comment: [An experimental dynamic allocator for PostgreSQL shared memory](https://github.com/ademakov/sharena), but it's 3 years old and not moving ..

Comment: You could write a script that gets the memory size and calculates settings based on that and updates the configuration file before starting Postgres.

Comment: `effective_cache_size` can be changed without restart using `alter system` (at least on a "vanilla" Postgres installation). But that setting does not allocate any memory at all - it's just a hint to the optimizer. Over allocating it won't prevent Postgres from starting